# What to choose WCF or WebAPI for mixed mode application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I have been using WCF for my web applications as it has the vast features of supporting multiple protocols, hosting with or without IIS and many other features though it is little confusion in understanding the configurations (ABCs) at client & server sides especially in terms of message sizes.

Though I haven't implemented applications using WebAPI but has got an idea as how it does the miracles with HTTP

I however need to decide for my new **mixed mode application** where the Service layer is common for both Mobile & Web based requests.

I do keep hearing about MVC6 but not sure how would it fit for my requirement.

So, trying to understand which one is more Apt for the requirement. Is this **WCF or Web API or MVC6**

Appreciate your master suggestions and thanks in advance.

Comment: read here https://blog.tonysneed.com/2016/01/06/wcf-is-dead-long-live-mvc-6/

Comment: @Singh, thanks for the URL. If MVC6 is yet to reach out to us... any suggestions about the rest of options for my scenario!

Comment: If you are talking about ASP.NET Core MVC, please use the correct tags. "ASP.NET 5 MVC6"  is now called "ASP.NET Core MVC (1.0)". The MVC6 tag is now reserved for a future version of ASP.NET MVC based on the **old** framework. ASP.NET Core MVC is a complete rewrite and not compatible with MVC5 based frameworks

Comment: Thank you @Tseng. I revised it.